# Estimating the rate of convergence of $|S_Nf-f|$ given that $\|f\|_{H^s}\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Given that the Soloblev space norm $$\|f\|_{H^s}^2=|\widehat{f}(0)|^2+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|n|^{2s}|\widehat{f}(n)|^2.$$
and the inequality 
$$\|f(\cdot +\theta)-f\|_{L^2}\leq 2\pi \|f\|_{H^s}|\theta|^s. $$
How do you show that $\|S_Nf-f\|_{L^2}$ converges at rate of $N$ alone, in fact, $|S_Nf-f|_2=O(N^{-s})$. So here is what I have
$$\left\|\sum_{n=-N}^N\widehat{f}(n)e^{2\pi xni}-f(x)\right\|_2$$
From here, how do you modify the inequality to obtain something like $$\|f(x+N^{-2s})-f(x)\|_{L^2}\leq2\pi |N|^{-s}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Parseval's identity

$$\left\|\sum_{n=-N}^N\widehat{f}(n)e^{2\pi xni}-f(x)\right\|_2^2 = 2\pi \sum_{|n| > N}|\widehat{f}(n)|^2.$$
$$=  2\pi N^{-2s} \sum_{|n| > N}|N^{s}\widehat{f}(n)|^2$$
$$\leq 2\pi N^{-2s} \sum_{|n| > N}|n^s\widehat{f}(n)|^2$$
$$\leq 2\pi N^{-2s}||f||_s^2$$
So $\|S_Nf-f\|_{L^2} \leq \sqrt{2\pi} N^{-s}||f||_s$ which gives you what you need. Note that actually
$\|S_Nf-f\|_{L^2} = o(N^{-s})$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I haven't learn Plancherel yet, from Wikipedia, it states the Plancherel theorem is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f|^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\widehat{f}|^2$$ Does your first equality follow from another version of this?

Comment: I guess Parseval's identity is the right name for this. It's the version of Plancherel's theorem for fourier series